# Why is Rails giving me this NoMethodError?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to make a profile page with my image repository and I am running into this error:

```
undefined method `images' for nil:NilClass

def show
        @user = User.find_by(username: params[:username])
        @images = @user.images.order(created_at: :desc) <<< (ERROR is occurring here)
    end
```

I looked everywhere to find the source of the problem, but I could not find it. I think I am missing something—I am new to rails. My routes are defined as such:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :images
  devise_for :users
  get '/upload', to: 'images#new'
  root 'images#index'

  get '/@image.user.full_name', to: 'users#show', as: :profile
  resources :images, only: [:index, :show, :create]

  delete 'images/:id(.:format)', :to => 'images#destroy'
end
```

Here is my users controller file:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
    def show
        @user = User.find_by(username: params[:username])
        @images = @user.images.order(created_at: :desc)
    end
end
```

And here is my users model:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
   # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable, :trackable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :validatable

  validates :username, presence: true, uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }
  validates :first_name, presence: true
  validates :last_name, presence: true

  has_many :images

  def full_name
    [first_name, last_name].join(' ')
  end
end
```

Here is a part of the schema:

```
create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "email", default: "", null: false
    t.string "encrypted_password", default: "", null: false
    t.string "reset_password_token"
    t.datetime "reset_password_sent_at"
    t.datetime "remember_created_at"
    t.string "username", null: false
    t.string "first_name", null: false
    t.string "last_name", null: false
    t.datetime "created_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.index ["email"], name: "index_users_on_email", unique: true
    t.index ["reset_password_token"], name: "index_users_on_reset_password_token", unique: true
    t.index ["username"], name: "index_users_on_username", unique: true
  end
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: It’s because the requested user doesn’t exist. You can use `find_by!` (with a `!`) to let Rails handle a missing / unknown user. The other “fix” is to provide an existing username when calling the page.

Answer (score 1):

When you get an `undefined method 'images' for nil:NilClass` then that means you call `images` on something that is `nil`.

In your code example, you have the following lines

```
@user = User.find_by(username: params[:username])
@images = @user.images.order(created_at: :desc)
```

in which you call `images` on `@user` and get that error. This means `@user` must be `nil` at that point. Since you assigned something to `@user` the line before that assignment must have assign `nil` to `@user`. The only reason why that might happen is when `User.find_by(username: params[:username])` was `nil`.

Seems like `params[:username]` didn't include a username that exists in your database it that `params[:username]` was not set at all.

Comment: Hi, I edited the post above to include my schema. The schema shows that "username" is in the database. I don't quite understand. Thanks

Comment: The error is not about a missing column in the database (then the error message would be different) it is that `params[:username]` is empty or contains an unknown username. `params` are generated via the routes from the URL that is called. How does the URL look like that you call? How does the log entry from your log file look like for that specific request?